# mysql max_binlog_size is not working

Tags: mysql, logs, binlog

I have a weird problem. I am currently using mysql and have defined 100M of max_binlog_size. However, I have hundreds of files created every day and each file is of no more then 2MB or 3MB each and sometime less.

I do not understand why is this so the file should be around 100M each?

Can someone have insights to it.

Answer (score 1):

When binary logs do not reach the limit set by [max_binlog_size](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replication-options-binary-log.html#sysvar_max_binlog_size), there are two(2) major reasons why

- mysqld closes the currently open binlog and opens a new binlog

  - Running `service mysql restart`
  - Running `service mysql top` followed by `service mysql start`
  - mysqld crashes and mysqld_safe restarts it if the mysqld crash was not severe
- Running [`FLUSH LOGS`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/flush.html) will do the following

  - Close and Reopen the Error Log
  - Close and Reopen the General Log
  - Close and Reopen the Slow Log
  - Close and Reopen Engine Logs
  - Close the Currently Open Binary Log and Open a New Binary Log

It says the following the [MySQL Documentation under `FLUSH LOGS`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/flush.html)

> With no log_type option, FLUSH LOGS closes and reopens all log files. ***If binary logging is enabled, the sequence number of the binary log file is incremented by one relative to the previous file***.

## SUGGESTIONS

- Look in your error log to see if mysqld crashes and restarts. The timestamp should match the binlog that was closed. The error log will also show the reason for the crash, or at least leave you a trail to attempt to troubleshoot
- If your code or some cronjob is running [FLUSH LOGS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/flush.html), do one of the following:

  - Replace it with `FLUSH ENGINE LOGS;`
  - Stop using `FLUSH LOGS` altogether
  - Live with it. Having 2M or 3M binary logs is not all that bad